# Why my Website getting zoomed in on phone devices

Tags: html, responsive-design, settings, viewport

I got a Single File Website witch reads xlsx Files out of a directory, theen it generates a select menu out of it.

You can select a file and it gets displayed with SimpleXLSX

My problem is that i cant get the site scaled down to bee shown in full witdh, on my phone it gets zoomed in and a have to slace it back ddown manually.

Can someone helb me with this problme?

```
<?php

use Shuchkin\SimpleXLSX;

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', true);


require_once __DIR__.'/simplexlsx/src/SimpleXLSX.php';


// Überprüfen, ob ein Dateipfad ausgewählt wurde
if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
    // Dateipfad in $fl speichern
    $fl = $_GET['file'];
}

$dir = './files'; // Pfad zum Ordner mit den Dateien
$fileList = glob($dir . '/*'); // Liest alle Dateien im Ordner ein

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Lieferanzeige</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
          font-size: 13px;
          font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 10px;
        }

        .geliefert {
          background-color: #b2f7d9;
        }

        select {
          width: 100%;
          padding: 10px;
          font-size: 20px;
          border: 1px solid #888;
          background-color: #f2f2f2;
          border-radius: 4px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        table {
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 95%;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        th,
        td {
          padding: 8px;
          border: 1px solid #ddd;
          text-align: left;
          font-size: 14px;
        }

        th {
          background-color: #f2f2f2;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: #333;
        }

        .header {
          background-color: #ddd;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: #333;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
          table {
            width: 100%;
          }
          select {
            width: 100%;
          }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- HTML-Formular -->
    <form method="get">
        <select name="file" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="">Bestellung wählen</option> <!-- Erste Option -->
            <?php foreach ($fileList as $file) {
            $dateiname = basename($file);
            $filename = basename($file, '.' . pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            if(substr($filename, -1) == 'H') {
                $filename = 'Herbst ' . substr($filename, 0, -1);
            } elseif(substr($filename, -1) == 'F') {
                $filename = 'Frühjahr ' . substr($filename, 0, -1);
            }
            // Option mit vollständigem Dateipfad als Wert und modifiziertem Dateinamen als Text
            echo '<option value="' . $dateiname . '">' . $filename . '</option>';
        } ?>        
        </select>
    </form>
    
    <?php if (isset($_GET['file'])) {?>
        <div class="head"> 
            <?php
                
                echo "Lieferstatus ";
                $flname = $fl;
                $flname = basename($flname, '.' . pathinfo($flname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                if(substr($flname, -1) == 'H') {
                    echo $flname = 'Herbst ' . substr($flname, 0, -1);
                } elseif(substr($flname, -1) == 'F') {
                    echo $flname = 'Frühjahr ' . substr($flname, 0, -1);
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        
        <?php       
        $pfad = $dir."/".$fl;
        
        //Prüfen ob datei existiert
        if (!file_exists($pfad)) {
            echo "Ausgewählte Datei nicht vorhanden!";
            exit();
        }

        // Prüfen, ob es sich um eine XLSX-Datei handelt
        if (!preg_match('/\.xlsx$/i', $pfad)) {
            echo "Kein XLSX File ausgewählt!";
            exit();
        }
        
        
        if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse($pfad) ) {
            $pos = count($xlsx->rows());
            $pos = $pos-1;      
        
            echo "<b>".$pos."</b> Bestellpositionen in Datei: <b>".$fl."</b> gefunden!";
            echo '<table id="brshop">';
            $z=0;
            foreach ($xlsx->rows() as $r) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<th class="' . (($z == 0) ? 'header' : (($r[4] != "xxx") ? 'geliefert' : '')) . '">' . (($z != 0) ? $z : '') . '</th>';
                echo '<th class="' . (($z == 0) ? 'header' : (($r[4] != "xxx") ? 'geliefert' : '')) . '">' . $r[0] . '</th>';
                echo '<th class="' . (($z == 0) ? 'header' : (($r[4] != "xxx") ? 'geliefert' : '')) . '">' . $r[1] . '</th>';
                echo '<th class="' . (($z == 0) ? 'header' : (($r[4] != "xxx") ? 'geliefert' : '')) . '">' . $r[3] . '</th>';
                echo '<th class="' . (($z == 0) ? 'header' : (($r[4] != "xxx") ? 'geliefert' : '')) . '">' . $r[5] . '</th>';
                echo '<th class="' . (($z == 0) ? 'header' : (($r[4] != "xxx") ? 'geliefert' : '')) . '">' . $r[6] . '</th>';
                echo '<th class="' . (($z == 0) ? 'header' : (($r[4] != "xxx") ? 'geliefert' : '')) . '">' . substr($r[4],0,11) . '</th>';

                echo '</tr>';
                $z++;
            }
            echo '</table>';
        } else {
            echo SimpleXLSX::parseError();
        }
        
    } // Ende if isset($_GET['file']
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I did ask google for help :) but all i can find was viewport settings and i try them but still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

@grandd For that issue you need to check that in mobile devices font-sizes above 16px. also you need to check there is any section or content overlap on horizontally.

Comment: thx, i did set all font size to moin 16px but that didnt change something. also there is no section overlaping.

Answer (score 0):

i think i got it.

i will test on more devices soon but on mine it works with fhis:

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).